# Relative url is not working in JavaScript (element.src)

Tags: javascript, url

I've written a simple html and js code to toggle between two images on click but relative url is not working in js code. code which is not working:

```
<a href="javascript:change()"><img id="demo" src="one.jpg" ></img></a>

<script>
var pic = document.getElementById("demo");
    function change()
    {
        if (pic.src == "one.jpg")
        {
            pic.src="two.jpg";
        }
        else
        {
            pic.src="one.jpg";
        }
    }
</script>
```

When I changed relative url to absolute its working fine:

```
<script>
var pic = document.getElementById("demo");
    function change()
    {
        if (pic.src == "file:///D:/javaScript_tut/one.jpg")
        {
            pic.src="file:///D:/javaScript_tut/two.jpg";
        }
        else
        {
            pic.src="file:///D:/javaScript_tut/one.jpg";
        }
</script>
```

Comment: before clicking, the image "one" is shown correcyly?

Comment: I would suggest adding ./ before the images names

Comment: yes one is shown correctly.
I tried adding pic.src="./two.jpg" still not working.

Comment: a stupid question: do you have the 'two.jpg' image in the same folder of the 'one.jpg'?

Comment: I think it's because the pic.src became the full path when you try to compare it in the-- if (pic.src == "one.jpg")

Comment: @SimoneRiboldi Yes both images are in same folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

replace

```
if (pic.src == "one.jpg")
```

with

```
if(pic.src.indexOf("one.jpg") >= 0)
```

Comment: worked!! Thanks for your efforts. I'll check details about indexOf() method on MDN, also it would be great if you can explain little bit working of above if statement.

Comment: and sorry, my reputation is below 15 so can't up-vote :)

Comment: @Gunner don't worry, I just wanted to help :), but you should be able to accept my answer